# 32bit intel assembly comparing and jumping

Tags: assembly, intel, 32-bit

This looks like this should work, but I keep getting a segmentation error right after I input the value. Any advice?

```
.section .data

speed: .int 0
fine: .int 0
points: .int 0

inputPrompt: .asciz "Enter an integer value for speed ==> "
outputPrompt: .asciz "With a speed of %d the fine will be $%d and %d points will be added to your license"

inputSpec: .ascii "%d"


.section .text #read in values

.globl main

main: 
    nop

    pushl   $inputPrompt

    call    printf

    addl    $4, %esp

#read in speed value    

    pushl   $speed

    pushl   $inputSpec

    call scanf

    addl    $8, %esp

#-------------------greater than or equal to 86--------------------------

movl    speed,   %eax

subl    $85,     %eax   

Jg  fine4

#-------------------81 - 85---------------------------------------------

movl    speed,   %eax

subl    $80,     %eax

Jg  fine3

#-------------------76 - 80---------------------------------------------

movl    speed,   %eax

subl    $75,     %eax   

Jg  fine2

#-------------------71 - 75---------------------------------------------

movl    speed,   %eax

subl    $70,     %eax   

Jg  fine1

#-----------------less than 71-----------------------------------------------

movl    $0,     fine
movl    $0,     points

JMP output

 #---------------------71 - 75-------------------------------------------

fine1:
movl    $60,        fine

movl    $2,     points

JMP output

#---------------------76 - 80-------------------------------------------

fine2:
movl    $90,        fine

movl    $3,     points

JMP output

#---------------------81 - 85-------------------------------------------

fine3:
movl    $120,       fine

movl    $4,     points

JMP output

#---------------------less than or equal to 86------------------------------------------

fine4:
movl    $150,       fine

movl    $6,     points

#----------------------------------------------------------------

output:
pushl   points
pushl   fine
pushl   speed
pushl   outputPrompt

call printf

addl $8, %esp

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
call exit
```

Comment: Is there a reason that inputSpec is .ascii rather than .asciz? scanf would expect this to be null-terminated, and that is a likely cause of the seg fault.

Comment: Is the crash during the call to scanf? If not, exactly which instruction is it on. If it is, then it could be from an unaligned stack, or from the lack of nul-termination James mentioned.

Comment: i changed inputSpec to .asciz and I'm still getting the segmentation fault at seemingly the same place. I'm running it in terminal so its not telling me where my error is coming from and I put 
`pushl speed
pushl testPrompt  # --> testPrompt: .asciz "the value is %d"
call printf
addl $8, %esp`
after the scanf to test if it even got past that point and it keeps segmentation faulting with no new output

Comment: What assembler are you using? How are you running the code?

Comment: There's a `cmp` instruction that will save you the trouble of re-loading the original after `sub`.  It sets flags the same as `sub`, but without writing the destination register.  Since your intervals are all the same, you could also check for > 71, then map the number to a lookup-table index (subtract 71 and divide by 5, then clamp the max index.)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `$` sign in `pushl outputPrompt`. That instruction puts the first 4 bytes of the `outputPrompt` on the stack, but you want the address. Hence use `pushl $outputPrompt`

Also, learn to use a debugger so that you can fix your own errors.